# Reference Request - Compact Hausdorff Space $K$ embeds into Measure Space $M(K)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

**Background:** For compact Hausdorff $X$, we can define $C(X)$ the Banach space of continuous functions and $M(X)$ the Banach space of finite signed regular Borel measures on $X$. By the Riesz-Markov theorem $M(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(X)^*$.

**Observation:** We can define the following map $\iota:X\to M(X)$ given by $\iota(x)=\delta_x$ where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta measure supported at $x$.  I can prove that $\iota$ is continuous and homeomorphic onto its image when $M(X)$ is given the weak-* topology. The same should hold for $X$ locally compact Hausdorff and $C_0(X)$ instead of $C(X)$.

**Reference Request:**
What I am looking for is a reference to this fact that I could direct others to (as opposed to having to prove it each time). The more standard the source the better of course. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is one of those statements that is "general knowledge" and that wouldn't need a reference or a proof.  In a paper, I would probably just write "... the natural embedding of $X$ into $M(X)$ ... ".  In notes for students, I would write "(left as an exercise)".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a feeling that might be the case. Even so, since my audience will have many non-mathematicians, I thought it might be good to find a reference where they could see such arguments for themselves.

Comment: I found a paper [Zbigniew Semadeni, “Spaces of continuous functions on compact sets”, Advances in Mathematics, 1:3 (1965), 319](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870865900411?via%3Dihub) or [on this website](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82196787.pdf). See theorem 1.3, though it only deals with the compact case.